# Opening a link with jQuery opens the relevant app but, proceeding this, an annoying about:blank page is opened. How can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome, hyperlink

(In chrome, on iOS)

The desired behaviour is the following:

1. The link will be opened in a new tab if the user doesn't have the app on their iOS device
2. The appropriate app will be opened if the user does have it installed, *without also opening an about:blank page*

---

I've tried the following:

```
window.open('link', '_blank'); // Opens app as desired but also about:blank

window.open('link'); // Opens app as desired but also about:blank

window.location = 'link'; // Opens app as desired with no about:blank page as
                          // desired BUT if the user doesn't have the app, it will
                          // open the link in the current window
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem... **(TL;DR at bottom)**

**Background**

Essentially, I have a link that did a short JavaScript animation when the user hovered over it.

If the user clicked the link before the hover animation had completed, the link would open immediately, so the snapshot taken by Chrome iOS would be incorrect. The snapshot shown by Chrome iOS when browsing open tabs needs to be done after the animation has completed so the reset animation on return to the page isn't jerky.

This means that a short (250ms) pause needs to happen whilst the animation completes before the link is followed, which cannot be done (as far as I'm aware) in pure HTML; it requires JavaScript.

So, using JavaScript to open a link after a delay, I came upon the above problem. Take, for example a link to Instagram. If the user does not have the Instagram app on their phone then, with JavaScript, the link will simply open in a new tab (this is good). If the user *does* have the Instagram app, a JavaScript call to open an Instagram link will first open an about:blank page, then open the Instagram app. This leaves an open about:blank page in Chrome iOS which is messy.

Eventually, I realised that HTML links (of the < a href = '...'>< /a> variety) are treated differently in mobile browsers than using pure JavaScript. HTML links work as expected with the caveat that in pure HTML you can't insert a delay before the link is opened.

**Solution**

The solution was to create a number of invisible HTML links in the following way

```
//HTML
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/xxxx/" id="aInstagram" target="_blank"></a>
```

In JavaScript you can then get that link by it's ID and, after a delay, call click() on it, exactly as if the user had.

```
// JavaScript
function instagramClicked() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('aInstagram').click();
    }, 250);
}
```

This provides the desired behaviour: the user clicks the Instagram icon and, after a delay, the Instagram app opens if it is installed, and the link is opened in a new tab if it is not.

**TL;DR**

I ended up using JavaScript to click an invisible HTML link after a delay due to differences in how HTML links and JavaScript links are followed